# Record Triggered Flow doesn't fire anymore on rollup summary field changes since rollout start Winter '21

Tags: visual-workflow, winter21

I have a Record Triggered Flow that doesn't fire anymore on rollup summary field changes but worked before. Does anybody know if there was a change?

I couldn't find any documentation which updates trigger the Record Triggered flow.

Best
Nina

Comment: They rolled out some stuff around ischanged in record triggered flows and in decision outcomes to allow testing if something has changed or not. Just a guess, but maybe that is related? See this article https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_record_triggered.htm?edition=&impact= and this article https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_trigger_specific_change.htm

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to open a Case, because this shouldn't have changed the behavior.

Comment: Are you using `before-` or `after-` record save in record-triggered flow? It works for me in case of before record-triggered flows and this makes sense as per SF documentation. Can you provide some details and screenshots of your flow config? And, whether the roll-up summary field gets updated conditionally?

Comment: I'm using the after-record save because I need to update another record, but good to hear that it works with a before-record save :) I will add screenshots later :)

Comment: I just did a quick test and it works for after-record save too. I tried an email notification (_instead of updating another record_) and it worked. So, the updates to roll-summary field does trigger this (`after`) record-triggered flow. It must be some problem within your flow logic.

Comment: @NinaRosen does the Flow happen to call any Apex?  (Recent critical update could have impacted if so)

Comment: Is the flow actually triggering per your debug logs? 

I had a weird scenario where the flow was firing but not correctly evaluating a decision element after the release. I checked the formula variable I was using in the decision and noticed there was a space on the end of every variable before the closing bracket e.g. {!$Record.Direct_Approval_From_Date__c } 

I removed the spaces and activated a new version and everything evaluated as expected. It didn't make much sense to me at the time (and reactivating the old version works as expected?!) so who knows.

Comment: @BrianDoogan that was the thing that solved my problem! Thank you! Would you like to add your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the flow actually triggering per your debug logs?

I had a weird scenario where the flow was firing but not correctly evaluating a decision element after the release. I checked the formula variable I was using in the decision and noticed there was a space on the end of every variable before the closing bracket e.g. {!$Record.Direct_Approval_From_Date__c }

I removed the spaces and activated a new version and everything evaluated as expected. It didn't make much sense to me at the time (and reactivating the old version works as expected?!) so who knows.