# Can a change to a roll-up summary field fire a record-triggered flow?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, roll-up-summary

The [SF Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5) states

> A roll-up summary field can trigger workflow rules and field validations.

Does this extend to record-triggered flows as well?

Comment: Yes. See this answer here which indicates it’s possible https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/324770/10073